# Tkinter passing an index when label is clicked from group of labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code to create a group of labels, with label_click_handler running when one of them is clicked:

```
def label_click_handler(i):
    print("Label " + str(i) + " pressed")
    # etc.

for i in range(10):
    label = Label(text="Label " + str(i))
    label.place(x=i*50, y=0)
    label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e:label_click_handler(i))
```

My issue is that clicking on any of the buttons will print the message:

```
Label 9 pressed
```

So the value of 9 (last in the range) is passed through to label_click_handler no matter which button is pressed.

How can I make the number of the button pressed get passed to label_click_handler?

Comment: this problem with `lambda` inside `for`-loop was many times on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `i=i` in the lambda function so `i` default value in function is set to the current `i` value.

```
def label_click_handler(i):
    print("Label " + str(i) + " pressed")
    # etc.

for i in range(10):
    label = Label(text="Label " + str(i))
    label.place(x=i*50, y=0)
    label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e,i=i:label_click_handler(i))
```